# Why takeWhile operator doesn't filter when inclusive?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to use takewhile operator with inclusive option set to true, and I'm facing a behavior I don't understand.
I've been able to isolate a little piece of code in which I can reproduce the behavior here

```
import { from, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';

const value$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1);

const source = value$.pipe(
  map(x => `value\$ = ${x}`),
  takeWhile(x => !x.includes('4'), /*inclusive flag: */true)
);

source.subscribe(x => {
  console.log(x); 
  value$.next(4); // Strange behavior only in this case
  });
```

explanation:
without the inclusive flag, it logs 'value$ = 1' and the stream completes

BUT, with the inclusive flag set to true, it falls with a stackoverflow exception
[image]

My question is, why does it go through the takeWhile more than once instead of stopping after the first occurrence?

here is a link of the bench is ever it helps to understand:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ag4aqx

Comment: By next()'ing back into the same Observable you are subscribed to within the subscription, you are setting up an infinite loop (every emission causes another next()'ed value, which causes another emission, and so on).  The only reason it doesn't show up when inclusive is false is because when inclusive is false, takeWhile doesn't emit the value that caused it to complete - but when it is true, it DOES emit the 4, which causes another 4 to be next()'ed, which causes another 4 to be emitted, etc, etc, which is the loop you are experiencing.

Comment: In other words, you set up a race condition between the completion logic and the emission of a new value.  Looks like the emission of the new value is winning.  :)

Comment: You're right @dmcgrandle thanks for spending time for replying. however I digged a little in the source code I found the operator shouldn't have been developped this way. I updated the stackblitz project with a custom takewhileinclusive operator and some explanations. I'll report a bug on rxjs github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging a little with the source code of the operator (https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/takeWhile.ts), there is indeed something wrong I gonna report as an issue to github.

in the meantime, here is a fixed custom takeWhileInclusive operator

```
import { from, BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';

/** Custom takewhile inclusive Custom takewhile inclusive properly implemented */
const customTakeWhileInclusive = <T>(predicate: (value: T) => boolean) => (source: Observable<T>) => new Observable<T>(observer => {
  let lastMatch: T | undefined // fix
  return source.subscribe({
    next: e => {
      if (lastMatch) {
        observer.complete();
      }
      else {
        if (predicate(e)) {
          /*
           *   Code from https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/takeWhile.ts
           *  
           *   if (this.inclusive) {
           *      destination.next(value); // NO! with a synchronous scheduler, it will trigger another iteration without reaching the next "complete" statement 
           *      and there is no way to detect if a match already occured!
           *   }
           *   destination.complete();
           */

          // Fix:
          lastMatch = e; // prevents from having stackoverflow issue here
        }

        observer.next(e);
      }
    },
    error: (e) => observer.error(e),
    complete: () => observer.complete()
  });
});

const value$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1);

const source = value$.pipe(
  map(x => `value\$ = ${x}`),
  //takeWhile(x => !x.includes('4'), true)
  customTakeWhileInclusive(x => x.includes('4'))  // fix
);

source.subscribe(x => {
  console.log(x);
  value$.next(4);
});
```

The problem with the actual operator is that in a synchronous scheduler context, when a match occurs it triggers another iteration and never reaches "complete".
The proper implementation would be to flag the match and perform another last iteration in which you complete detecting the flag.

Link to the updated stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ag4aqx